# A function such that it has a root of infinite multiplicity at $x=1$, and the coefficients of its Taylor series around $x=0$ converge to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, taylor-expansion

I was working on another problem, and the last step to prove it would be finding a function like this. So to be clear, I am looking for a function $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ such that $0=f(1)=f'(1)=f''(1)=\ldots$ , and $a_n\to 0$, and there exists a nonzero coefficient. I might be just too tired, but I haven't been able to think of one. Does a function like this exist?

Comment: what do you mean by $f'(1)$ etc

Comment: The derivative of the function $f(x)$ evaluated at the point $x=1$.

Comment: Fair enough, I forgot that the trivial $f(x)=0$ solution is ruled out by the original constraints of the problem. Will edit.

Comment: I get that but what does that mean exactly - you assume $f$ is differentiable on some open interval containing $0,1$ and is analytic at $0$ with power series coefficients satisfying $a_n \to 0$ but $f^{(n)}(1)=0$ for all $n \ge 0$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.

Comment: I think we are missing some condition about on what domain $f$ is supposed to be analytic here.

Comment: Or, as $a_n \to 0$, it is analytic in the interior of the unit disk; but it cannot be analytic at $1$ because otherwise it would have to be identically $0$ in a disk around $1$ and hence also inside the unit circle.

Comment: note that $e^{-1/(x-1)^2}$ satisfies most of the conditions but not necessarily $a_n \to 0$; also note that you can always replace $a_n \to 0$ by $a_n << n^k$ for some fixed $k$ since you can take an appropriate antiderivative to make $b_n=a_n/n^{k+1} \to 0, n \ge 1$ and modify it with a polynomial to preserve the condition at $1$

Comment: Maybe I should mention the context this question came up in. If $A=(a_0, a_1, a_2, \ldots)$, then define $SA=(a_0, a_0+a_1, a_0+a_1+a_2, \ldots)$, so the sequence of partial sums. The question was, is there a sequence $A$ such that $A, SA, SSA, \ldots$ are all convergent? I defined the function $f(x)$ as in the question. It is easy to see that $a_n\to0$, otherwise $SA$ wouldn't converge. Similarly for $SA$, so $f(1)=0$. Let $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{1-x}$, then the coefficients of $g(x)$ are the sequence $SA$. Similarly, $g(1)=0$. And we can repeat this process again and again.

Comment: So this function $f$ has root of infinite multiplicity at $1$, and the coefficients are going to zero, that's why I was looking for a function like this.

Comment: actually there are such functions for which $a_n \to 0$ quite fast - they are described in Polya Szego Theorems and Problems in Analysis volume 1 problem 250, p 154 - for example $f(x)=\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t^{1/3}/2}\sin (\sqrt 3 t^{1/3} /2)e^{-t(1-x)}dt, -1<x<1, e^{-1/(x-1)^2}, x \ge 1$ satisfies the required properties: it is $C^{\infty}$ on $(-1, \infty)$, analytic on the interval $(-1,1)$ and if $F(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ there we have $|a_n| << e^{-(1/2-\epsilon)n^{1/3}}$ for every $\epsilon>0$

Comment: note that since $\sum n^k|a_n| < \infty$ for all $k$ it follows that all the series corresponding to (formally) differentiating the power series of $f, k$ times converge absolutely at $1$ and of course by general theory the result is $0$ so indeed $a_n$ satisfy the required property that $A, SA, SSA, \ldots$ are all convergent

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems to be correct; but I think it might be a little overkill for this question. One thing I noticed is that we don't actually need $0=f(1)=f'(1)=\ldots$, only that the left-hand limits at $1$ equal $0$. With that in mind, $f(x)=e^{\frac{1}{x-1}}$ could work. I have checked numerically, and the coefficients of the Taylor series seem to be converging to $0$, but I haven't been able to prove it yet.

Comment: I would like to see a proof of the growth rate of the coefficients of $e^{1/(x-1)}$ though note that the convergence of the series you mention requires much more than the existence and nullity of those derivatives since that implies only Abel convergence - one problem is that the partial series of $e^{-y}$ can get very big before they get very small when $y>0$ is large

Comment: You can actually compute explicitly $a_n$ for $e^{1/(x-1)}$ or $e^{-1/(x-1)^2}$ but at a quick glance I am not sure they actually go to zero